# Antonym for "ad hoc"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am going to find an appropriate antonym for "ad hoc" (done for a particular purpose only) to be used as the adjective of a kind of general-purpose device. The best choice can be "general-purpose", itself, or maybe versatile.
I couldn't find an antonym in common sources. Can anyone suggest the best choice?

E.g. A general-purpose robot

Comment: Please add in an example sentence where you would use this word.

Comment: how about "planned, nonspecific, general"

Comment: A sentence such as: "This appliance is _______ ." This is a/an ________ device"

Comment: @etash I would like it to be one-word for title

Comment: @mari-lou You mean these sentences are better than using "general-purpose"?

Comment: No, a sentence where you would use the antonym. Presumably you would use this word in a description of some kind. The ____ indicates where the word would go. I was echoing Matt's request. @Etash, comments are there to ask for clarifications, or sometimes the answer is so obvious we may post it in a comment and then vote to close the question. Why not write an answer?

Comment: An *antonym* can depend on the implicit viewpoint from which the user is approaching it. (If you look at my comment on the next succeeding question, concerning the antonym of *delegate*, you will see my point. Thus you do need to supply an intended usage.

Comment: The literal antonym for _ad hoc_ in Latin is _ab istud_ or _ab illud_. _Ad hoc_ means "to this (here by me)", _ab istud_ means "from that (there by you)", and _ab illud_ means "from that (over there)". _Hoc, istud,_ and _illud_ are all neuter accusative pronouns, and can be used for places like _here_ and _there_ as well as things.

Comment: The problem, of course, is that _ad hoc_ is an English idiom, meaning what it means in English, not Latin; while the phrases I suggested are simply that -- Latin phrases -- that aren't idiomatic in English and have no specific English meanings outside their Latin original meanings, which very few English speakers will understand, especially in speech. Gratuitous use of unusual foreign phrases in English without any translation is not a mark of good style.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree but I am interested in them because one probable use is being used as two words (ab & illud) in an acronym (including A for 'ab' and I for 'illud'). Just I wanted to know if I can claim that these two words can stand for "general-purpose" in English or something near to it.

Comment: You can claim anything you want, but unless others agree with you it won't be accepted. English is not something a single person can influence in any recognizable way.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't mean I will claim it as an English word. If I want to change my question, I can say that: Latin speaking, is "ad hoc" used as single-purpose meaning and "ab illud" as an antonym for that (forgetting about english)

Comment: No, it's not an antonym; that's the point. Latin has a three-way deictic system: _hoc_ 'here (by me)', _istud_ 'there (by you)', _illud_ 'over there; yonder'. So there are no "opposites"; it's three-dimensional. English deixis only has two distinctions -- distal _there_ and proximal _here_ -- but the distinction between _illud_ and _istud_ is not made. Spanish still has _este, ese, aquello_, which are like Latin.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, if I understood right, Latin speakers used 'ad hoc' only for saying 'from here' and did not use it for saying 'single purpose', at all?

Comment: Don't know. Ask a Latin speaker or a Classic scholar. I'm a general linguist and don't speak any dead languages conversationally,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "universal, overall, versatile, general, multiuse, flexible".

Edit:

> Ad-hoc / general-purpose: Able to accommodate multiple uses

You can use

> universal : The definition of universal is relating to or affecting all.

ex  1: An example of universal used as an adjective is a `universal` curfew for a town which means that all members of that town must be home by a certain time.

ex  2: Adapted or adjustable to many sizes, uses, or devices: a `universal` remote control.

> Versatile :  The definition of versatile is having many uses.

Exclusively designed collections offer `versatile`, mix and match outfits, in a variety of color palettes.

> overall : The definition of overall is including everything or in general.

ex  1:  An example of `overall` used as an adjective is in the phrase "the overall taste of the pizza," which means the general taste of the pizza.

Comment: This list appears in this order at a number of locations. If you have quoted another site, you must [quote and reference it correctly](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 4):

*[systematic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/systematic)*:

> adjective
>
> Done or acting according to a fixed plan or system; methodical:

*[ad hoc](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ad-hoc?q=ad%20hoc)*:

> adjective& adverb
>
> Created or done for a particular purpose as necessary:

Answer (score 1):

**premediative**:think 
out or plan , an action beforehand.
or, **rehearsed**